# Como retorno um valor aleatório do meu banco de dados já exibindo em outra guia?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Quero retornar um valor aleatório do banco e já exibir em outra guia, atraves de uma função. Pra quando eu clicar em enviar já chama essa função.

Controller

```
public ActionResult RetornarVideoAleatorio(int id) 
    {
        var lista = db.Videos.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(lista);
    }
```

HTML

```
<section id="main"><form>
<input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" value="" required="" placeholder="Titulo" />

<input type="text" id="video-url" name="url" required="" value="" placeholder="url" />

<button id="submit" onclick="funcaoOnclick();">Enviar Video</button>
</form>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
function RetornarUrl(id) {

    var url = "/Video/RetornarVideoAleatorio" + id;

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: id }
        , datatype: "Json"
        , success: function (data) {
            alert("retornou");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Erro");
        }
    });

}

function funcaoOnclick() {
    SalvarItens()
    RetornarUrl(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não seria só colocar dentro de success?

```
$.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: id }
        , datatype: "Json"
        , success: function (data) {
            alert("retornou");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Erro");
        },
success: function (){
 funcaoOnclick();
    }
    });
```